# get html content windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

hi i asked for an alternatif for Windows phone to get the  HTML content of the webpage like this
in wpf

```
 var doc = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser2.Document;
                var head = doc.getElementsByTagName("head").Cast<HTMLHeadElement>().First();
                var script = (IHTMLScriptElement)doc.createElement("script");

                //script.src = @"getSelectedText.js";
```

so i would append a script javascript to my html which has already been displayed in the browser
i find browser.savetostring but it return a string not a html 
i didn't find any support 
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can download a `HTML` via `WebClient` for example, inject your `JavaScript` and display result in a `WebBrowser` with `NavigateToString` method.